# How do I modify the part 4 of G.Shell.GGIR function in R if I do not have a sleep log

Tags: r-package

I am trying to analyse physical activity data collected from geneactiv accelerometer using the GGIR shell function in R (code copied from ). The Part 4 section of the code requires comparing the sleep data generated by the accelerometer and a self-reported sleep log. The "loglocation" argument requires you to enter the CSV filename for the manual sleep log. However my study does not include the self-reported sleep log as I am mainly interested in physical activity levels not sleep analysis. How do I modify the code to exclude including the sleep log and get my code to run successfully and produce the necessary visual data? Please find below the R code for physical activity analysis.

```
library(GGIR)
g.shell.GGIR(#=======================================
             # INPUT NEEDED:
             mode=c(1,2,3,4,5),
             datadir="C:/hadiza/mydata",
             outputdir="D:/myresults",
             f0=1, f1=2,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 1:
             #-------------------------------
             # Key functions: reading file, auto-calibration, and extracting features
             do.enmo = TRUE,             do.anglez=TRUE,
             chunksize=1,                printsummary=TRUE,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 2:
             #-------------------------------
             strategy = 2,               ndayswindow=7,
             hrs.del.start = 0,          hrs.del.end = 0,
             maxdur = 9,                 includedaycrit = 16,
             winhr = c(5,10),
             qlevels = c(c(1380/1440),c(1410/1440)),
             qwindow=c(0,24),
             ilevels = c(seq(0,400,by=50),8000),
             mvpathreshold =c(100,120),
             bout.metric = 4,
             closedbout=FALSE,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 3:
             #-------------------------------
             # Key functions: Sleep detection
             timethreshold= c(5),        anglethreshold=5,
             ignorenonwear = TRUE,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 4:
             #-------------------------------
             # Key functions: Integrating sleep log (if available) with sleep detection
             # storing day and person specific summaries of sleep
             excludefirstlast = TRUE,
             includenightcrit = 16,
             def.noc.sleep = c(),
             loglocation= "C:/mydata/sleeplog.csv",
             outliers.only = TRUE,
             criterror = 4,
             relyonsleeplog = FALSE,
             sleeplogidnum = TRUE,
             colid=1,
             coln1=2,
             do.visual = TRUE,
             nnights = 9,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 5:
             # Key functions: Merging physical activity with sleep analyses
             #-------------------------------
             threshold.lig = c(30), threshold.mod = c(100),  threshold.vig = c(400),
             boutcriter = 0.8,      boutcriter.in = 0.9,     boutcriter.lig = 0.8,
             boutcriter.mvpa = 0.8, boutdur.in = c(1,10,30), boutdur.lig = c(1,10),
             boutdur.mvpa = c(1),   timewindow = c("WW"),
             #-----------------------------------
             # Report generation
             #-------------------------------
             # Key functions: Generating reports based on meta-data
             do.report=c(2,4,5),
             visualreport=TRUE,     dofirstpage = TRUE,
             viewingwindow=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this part `loglocation= "C:/mydata/sleeplog.csv"` work for me.

```
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 4:
             #-------------------------------
             # Key functions: Integrating sleep log (if available) with sleep detection
             # storing day and person specific summaries of sleep
             excludefirstlast = TRUE,
             includenightcrit = 16,
             def.noc.sleep = c(),
             #loglocation= "C:/mydata/sleeplog.csv",
             outliers.only = TRUE,
             criterror = 4,
             relyonsleeplog = FALSE,
             sleeplogidnum = TRUE,
             colid=1,
             coln1=2,
             do.visual = TRUE,
             nnights = 9,
```

And this is the same solution that is shown in this video https://youtu.be/S8YPTrYNWdU?t=219